# animate to right on scroll down and animate back to the left on scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do an animation on page scroll where selected element will animate from left to right on scroll down and if back to top then animate the selected element from right to left (default position), here's what I tried

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var wS = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (wS <= 10) {

      $("#test-box").animate({
        'left': 100
      }, 500);

    }
    if (wS > 11) {

      $("#test-box").animate({
        'left': $('#main-container').width() - 100
      }, 500);


    }

  });

});
```

```css
#main-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 500px;
}

#test-box {
  background: red;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 100;
  top: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-container">
  <div id="test-box">test</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, on scroll down, the test box moves as I instruct but when scroll up, it does not go to the left as default, any ideas, help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a global variable to control the animation. See the working snippet below please, where I've commented parts of the code that I added:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var animated = false; //added variable to control the animation
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (animated && wS <= 10) {
      $("#test-box").animate({
        'left': 100
      }, 500);
      animated = false; //animation ended
    }
    if (!animated && wS > 11) {
      $("#test-box").animate({
        'left': $('#main-container').width() - 100
      }, 500);
      animated = true; //it was animated
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#main-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 500px;
}

#test-box {
  background: red;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 100px;
  top: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-container">
  <div id="test-box">test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, it also uses css for the animation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var box = document.querySelector('#test-box');
  var stateClass = '-right';
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
    box.classList.toggle(stateClass, document.body.scrollTop > 10);
  });
});
```

```css
#main-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 2000px;
}

#test-box {
  background: red;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 100px;
  top: 10;
  transition: .5s linear;
}

#test-box.-right {
  left: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-100%) translateX(-100px)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-container">
  <div id="test-box">test</div>
</div>
```